# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke"org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)"because"this.searchContext"is null

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, page-factory

Help I don't know what is wrong with my code

**Displayed Error**

```
FAILED: test.RegistrationForUserAccount.RegisterUser
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.SearchContext.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.searchContext" is null
```

```
public class BrowserStartAndLandSite {
    
    public static WebDriver driver;
    
    public WebDriver StartBrowserWithSite() throws IOException {
        
        Properties obj = new Properties();
        FileInputStream objfile = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\java\\resources\\browser.properties");
        obj.load(objfile);
        String browser = obj.getProperty("browser_name");
        String url = obj.getProperty("urlOfSite");
        
        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get(url);
        }
        
        
        else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
            WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get(url);
        }
        
        else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("edge")) {
            WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
            driver = new EdgeDriver();
            driver.get(url);
        }
        
        return driver;
    }

}



public class LandingSite {
    
    WebDriver driver;
    
    public LandingSite(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
    
    @FindBy(xpath="//a[@class='login']")
    WebElement signInButton;
    
    
    public void ClickSignIn() {
        signInButton.click();
    }

}





public class RegistrationForUserAccount extends BrowserStartAndLandSite {
    
    @Test
    public void RegisterUser() throws IOException {
        
        
        LandingSite ls = new LandingSite(driver);
        ls.ClickSignIn();
    }

}
```